# Matching inner pattern an unlimited amount of times within outer pattern

Tags: regex

Say I have the following pattern:

`INDICATOR\s+([a-z0-9]+)`

which would match for example:

`INDICATOR AA` or `INDICATOR B3`

I need to edit this pattern so it matches any instances of a string which starts with `INDICATOR` has a space and then has multiple matches of the inner pattern e.g.

`INDICATOR AA A3 66 B8 34 CD`

`INDICATOR BG 4D CS`

`INDICATOR HG`

Is it possible to do this?

**Solution**

With thanks to Gumbo I came up with the following regex which suits my requirements:

`INDICATOR((\s+)?([,-])?(\s+)?([a-z0-9]+))+`

Comment: Your improved regex will also match `INDICATORXYZ123OU812` (assuming a case-insensitive match, of course).  Do you really want to match strings like `INDICATOR AABB`, as you indicated in one of your comments?  And what regex flavor are you using, anyway?

Comment: @Alan: Just noticed your comment. Yes I do want to match the patterns like you said. The pattern I am using is a bit more complex than the example one, so it is safe to allow them to have no spaces. I want to make sure if the input doesn't have spaces the patterns are still picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INDICATOR(\s+([a-z0-9]+))+
```

Here the repeating pattern is wrapped in a group and quantified using `+` to allow one or more repetitions of the expression inside the group. But you won’t get every match of the inner group with this but only the last match (or to be more specific: it depends on the implementation you’re using).

Comment: @Gumbo: Basically I just need to match the full string and then I will reparse it using only the inner regex to get the data out. This initial regex is for validation.

Comment: @James: Then I suggest using so called non-capturing groups `(?:…)` instead of “normal” groups to avoid the costs of storing the captured string.

Comment: @Gumbo: Does this give me the advantage of not having to re-parse the string I can just iterate over the groups?

Comment: No you will always have to re-parse the group if you want the individual values. Regex cannot recursively capture values in that matter. If you use a quantifier on a capture group, the group only contains the last value matched.

Comment: Say the pattern might have a different separator instead of a space i.e. a comma or a hyphen. Would I just replace the `\s+` with something like `[(\s+),-]` ?

Comment: @James: If you would allow one or more spaces but only one single comma/hyphen, you would need `(\s+|[,-])`. Otherwise, if it is always just one character, `[\s,-]`.

Comment: @Cags: There are implementations that store each single match of a repetition (I think [.NET’s CaptureCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection\(v=VS.71\).aspx) provides such a behavior).

Comment: @Gumbo , ah true, for some reason I'd got it in my head he was using PHP.

Comment: @Gumbo: I want to allow spaces & hyphens incase input is like: `INDICATOR AA, BB, CC` or even `INDICATOR AA ,BB , CC`. Same would go for the hypen (or any other separator I intend to use).

Comment: I ended up with the following `INDICATOR((\s+)?([,-])?(\s+)?([a-z0-9]+))+`. This would allow all variations of `INDICATOR AA, BB`, `INDICATOR AA,BB`, `INDICATOR AABB`, `INDICATOR AA , BB`, `INDICATOR AA BB` which keeps my pattern flexible. I need to try support all these different situations as I can't guarentee how the users will send the information in a strict format.

Comment: @Gumbo: Just one more thing (not really a necessity but would be nice). Is it possible to restrict the amount of patterns I match? i.e instead of matching all, can I restrict it to only match the first 20?

Comment: @James: Yes, you can use the quantifier `{n,m}` to allow n to m repetitions. So try `INDICATOR(\s*[,-\s]\s*[a-z0-9]+){1,20}`.